# Confuse on proof of theorem 22.9 (White-path theorem) Depth-First search (DFS) on Cormen-Leiserson-Rivest-Stein "Introduction to algorithms" book

Tags: algorithms, graphs, depth-first-search

I'm reading the DFS section of CLRS-*Introduction to Algorithms*, and confuse on the $\Leftarrow$ direction of the proof of the white-path theorem of DFS algorithm in this book. 
Note that each node u in the graph has 2 **timestamps**: $u.d$ records when u is discovered and $u.f$ records when the search ﬁnishes examining u’s adjacency list .

Dependencies:

> **Theorem 22.7 (Parenthesis theorem)**
> In any depth-ﬁrst search of a (directed or undirected) graph $G = (V, E)$, for any
> two vertices u and v, exactly one of the following three conditions holds:
>
> - the intervals $[u.d, u.f]$ and $[v.d, v.f]$ are entirely disjoint, and neither u nor v
>   is a descendant of the other in the depth-ﬁrst forest,
> - the interval $[u.d, u.f]$ is contained entirely within the interval $[v.d, v.f]$, and u
>   is a descendant of v in a depth-ﬁrst tree, or
> - the interval $[v.d, v.f]$ is contained entirely within the interval $[u.d, u.f]$, and v
>   is a descendant of u in a depth-ﬁrst tree.

> **Corollary 22.8 (Nesting of descendants’ intervals)**
> Vertex v is a proper descendant of vertex u in the depth-ﬁrst forest for a (directed
> or undirected) graph G if and only if $u.d < v.d < v.f < u.f$.

Proof of theorem 22.9:

> **Theorem 22.9 (White-path theorem)**
> In a depth-ﬁrst forest of a (directed or undirected) graph $G = (V, E)$, vertex v is
> a descendant of vertex u if and only if at the time $u.d$ that the search discovers u,
> there is a path from u to v consisting entirely of white vertices.
>
> **Proof** $\Rightarrow$: If $v = u$, then the path from u to v contains just vertex u, which is still white when we set the value of $u.d$. Now, suppose that v is a proper descendant of u in the depth-ﬁrst forest. By Corollary 22.8, $u.d < v.d$, and so v is white at time $u.d$. Since v can be any descendant of u, all vertices on the unique simple
> path from u to  in the depth-ﬁrst forest are white at time $u.d$.
>
> $\Leftarrow$ Suppose that there is a path of white vertices from u to v at time $u.d$, but v does not become a descendant of u in the depth-ﬁrst tree. Without loss of generality, assume that every vertex other than v along the path becomes a descendant of u.(Otherwise, let v be the closest vertex to u along the path that doesn’t become a descendant of u.) **Let $w$ be the predecessor of v in the path, so that $w$ is a descendant
> of u (w and u may in fact be the same vertex)**. By Corollary 22.8, $w.f \leq u.f$ . Because v must be discovered after u is discovered, but before w is ﬁnished, we have $u.d < v.d < w.f \leq u.f$ . Theorem 22.7 then implies that the interval $[v.d, v.f]$ is contained entirely within the interval $[u.d, u.f]$. By Corollary 22.8, v must after
> all be a descendant of u.

In the proof, they **let $w$ be the predecessor of v in the path**. How do we know that such a $w$ exists? And if such $w$ exists, whether or not theorem 22.7 and corollary 22.8 are unnecessary, because i think if $w$ is predecessor of v, so that v is descendant of w, which directly implies that v is descendant of u?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I will still try to answer.

The predecessor of $v$ in a path from $u$ to $v$ is the last vertex seen before $v$.

Since there exists a path from $u$ to $v$ then, unless $v = u$, $v$ has necessarily a predecessor.

More formally, if $(u_0, u_1, …, u_k)$ is a path of length $k$ from $u = u_0$ to $v = u_k$, then the predecessor of $v$ is $u_{k-1}$. It exists unless $u = v$.

Comment: if w is predecessor of v in the path, so that v is w's descendant. i think it directly implies that v is descendant of u and theorem 22.7, corollary 22.8 is unnecessary

Comment: @minhquýlê your question was "How do we know that such a $w$ exists?". Your comment suggests that you meant something more than just this question. Please be precise in your post in what you are asking.